# Filtering a table in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter

How can I easily filter a table in Matlab? Let's say I want to filter a table and only keep rows where the value in column 5 is larger than 30. How does this work?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this just like you would [normal logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7ekiy-1).

```
tbl = table(rand(10,1), rand(10,1), 'VariableNames', {'a', 'b'});

     a          b   
  _______    _______

  0.64432    0.20774
  0.37861    0.30125
  0.81158    0.47092
  0.53283    0.23049
  0.35073    0.84431
    0.939    0.19476
  0.87594    0.22592
  0.55016    0.17071
  0.62248    0.22766
  0.58704     0.4357
```

Now we grab all rows where column `a` is greater than 0.5 (`tbl.a > 0.5`)

```
tbl(tbl.a > 0.5,:)

     a          b   
  _______    _______

  0.64432    0.20774
  0.81158    0.47092
  0.53283    0.23049
    0.939    0.19476
  0.87594    0.22592
  0.55016    0.17071
  0.62248    0.22766
  0.58704     0.4357
```

You can also access it using the column *index*.

```
tbl(tbl{:,1} > 0.5,:)
```

For your case this would be `tbl(tbl{:,5} > 30,:)`

More information about accessing table data [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html).

Comment: Thanks for your support. Looks super logical, however, I get the following error again: "Undefined operator '>' for input arguments of type 'cell'". I know that I still have one 'cell' type input within one of my columns. Is there a way to transfer the whole table upfront so that I can apply the filtering?

Comment: @user3261573 What does your actual table data look like?

Comment: One of the columns has cell arrays in it. That might cause the problem. Do you know a way how to solve it?

Comment: @user3261573 So it's column 5 that has cells? How do you expect to do that comparison with 30 then?

Comment: No, it is in another column - not the one that is filtered.

Comment: @user3261573 Should be updated now. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: What do you do when some values are of the type cell?

Comment: @JohnAndrews You need to come up with a scheme to create a logical array from you cell arrays. There's no general solution for that, it really depends on your data.

Comment: Note: If you want to specify the column by name and the contents of the column is cell, you can do `tbl(tbl.a{:,1} >0.5, :)`. Notice that it is important to specify the dimension 1 inside a.

Comment: I assume filtering with comparisons like `<`, `>`, `<=` and `=>` might lead to problems due to the floating point precision in matlab. Maybe a tolerance with `eps` should be added. What do you think?

Comment: @KenJiiii Sure, you could do that but that is specific to floating point numbers whereas this question is just with respect to filtering based on some comparison operator and the answer as-is still conveys that. The user could easily use `eps` if they needed to perform floating point comparisons (particularly for `==`)